Use pgf string as property value
I'm trying to set anchor based on direction, like that:
\newcommand{\angletodirection}[1]{
    \pgfmathparse{{"south west", "south east", "north east", "north west"}[int(mod(floor(#1/90)+4, 4))]}\pgfmathresult
}

...

\node[anchor={\angletodirection{\ang}}] at (cpoint) {##1};

But that doesn't work.
Minimal reproducable example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\angletodirection}[1]{
    \pgfmathparse{
        {"south west", "south east", "north east", "north west"}[int(mod(floor(##1/90)+4, 4))]
    }
    \pgfmathresult
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ang}{20} % 0-360

    % What is working: 
    \node[anchor=south west] at (0, 0) {\angletodirection{\ang+90}}; 

    % What i want (compile error):
    % \node[anchor={\angletodirection{\ang+90}}] at (0, 0) {Text}
    
    \filldraw (0, 0) circle (0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Are you sure that code even compiles on its own? I tried running it outside of the \node and it fails immediately.

@daleif exclude line that marked as (didn't work)

That is what I'm saying removing that line and tying to run \angletodirection{0+90} manually fails. (btw it should be #1 not ##1)

@daleif and THAT the problem. That command returnts string object or something like that. How do i suppose to use it, or maybe there better way to do such thing?

There are other methods. What exactly is the int(mod(floor(#1/90)+4, 4) trying to do here? Integer value of #1/90 add 4, then run mod 4?

@daleif Its converting 360-0 to 3-0. Anyway thats method working perfectly (i update the answer to show it) when i use it as text

You can't use PGFMath that way. The anchor key only accepts either one of the textual anchors or something that can be thrown into PGFMath and returns a number. You're basically asking TikZ to do \pgfmathparse{\pgfmathparse{…}\pgfmathresult}. This breaks. Removing both \pgfmathparse and \pgfmathresult so that you just specify {…}[…] as a parameter to anchor would be valid but at that point only angles are allowed, not the textual anchors. You can use your own key: angle to direction/.code=\pgfmathparse{{…}[…]}\tikzset{anchor/.expanded=\pgfmathresult}.

I don't think you can use \pgfmathparse in the value for anchor.
You can do the job in two steps:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\angletodirection}[1]{%
  \pgfmathparse{int(mod(floor((#1)/90)+4, 4))}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\todir}{%
    {"south west", "south east", "north east", "north west"}[\pgfmathresult]%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ang}{20} % 0-360

    \angletodirection{\ang}
    \node[anchor=\todir] at (0, 0) {Text};

    \angletodirection{\ang+90}
    \node[anchor=\todir] at (0, 0) {Text};

    \angletodirection{\ang+180}
    \node[anchor=\todir] at (0, 0) {Text};

    \angletodirection{\ang+270}
    \node[anchor=\todir] at (0, 0) {Text};

    \filldraw (0, 0) circle (0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


I guess you want to compute (\ang+90)/90+4 and not, as you wrote, \ang+90/90+4, so I used (#1) instead of just #1.
Alternative version with expl3:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\angletodirection}{m}{%
  \int_case:nn { \int_mod:nn { \fp_eval:n {floor((#1)/90)+4} } { 4 } }
   {
    {0}{south~west}
    {1}{south~east}
    {2}{north~east}
    {3}{north~west}
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ang}{20} % 0-360

    \node[anchor=\angletodirection{\ang}] at (0, 0) {Text 0};
    \node[anchor=\angletodirection{\ang+90}] at (0, 0) {Text 90};
    \node[anchor=\angletodirection{\ang+180}] at (0, 0) {Text 180};
    \node[anchor=\angletodirection{\ang+270}] at (0, 0) {Text 270};

    \filldraw (0, 0) circle (0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



A crutch, but at least a working solution. Thank you!

@ШвеевАлексей Look at the second version.

looks better! thanks
